# On Ford's "The distribution of integers with a divisor in a given interval"

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Let $H(x,y,z)$ denote the number of positive integers of size at most $x$ which have a divisor in the range $(y,z]$. In his famous "The distribution of integers with a divisor in a given interval" (Ann. of Math. 168, 367–433, 2008), Ford proves in Theorem 2 that
$$
H(x,y,z) - H(x-\Delta,y,z) \asymp \frac{\Delta}{x} H(x,y,z),
$$
provided that
$
x/(\log z)^{10} \leq \Delta \leq x.$

Before the statement of the theorem, he writes "The range of $\Delta$ can
be considerably improved, but the given range suffices for the application..."

Question: How far can the range of $\Delta$ be improved, and is such an improvement available anywhere in the literature?